# Elvis operator, return if != null or do something entirely different

Tags: kotlin

I have a model called Subscription and a service trying to receive that subscription but if the subscription is not existing I'd like to call a different service.

What I aimed for:

```
val recipientSubscription = subscribeService.getSubscription(pushMessage.recipient)
        ?: cachingService.add(pushMessage)
```

but this does not work because now recipientSubscription is not of type subscription anymore.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Can you show me the return types of `getSubscription` and `cachingService.add(pushMessage)`?

Comment: If both calls don'treturn the same type, maybe you shouldn't use elvis operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return types of `subscribeService.getSubscription(pushMessage.recipient)` and `cachingService.add(pushMessage)` are **NOT identical** thus creating an error. The return type of the `default` value should be the same as the nullable value.

Here is my example:

```
    val a: Int? = null //a is integer
    val b: Int = a ?: 3 //Valid, default value of b is 3, which is integer
    val c: Int = a ?: "s" //<-- Invalid, default value is not Integer
```

Let me know if you have more questions.

**EDIT**

**Style 1** (more `Java` Like) : Using Traditional if-else approach

```
    var recipientSubscription = subscribeService.getSubscription(pushMessage.recipient)
    if (recipientSubscription == null) {
        cachingService.add(pushMessage) //Add subscription.
        recipientSubscription = subscribeService.getSubscription(pushMessage.recipient) //set subscription again.
    }
```

**Style 2** (more `Kotlin` Like) : Using [Kotlin's `run` scope function](http://**Style%201**%20(more%20Java%20Like)%20:%20Using%20Traditional%20if-else%20approach) approach

```
    val recipientSubscription = subscribeService.getSubscription(pushMessage.recipient)
        ?: run {
           cachingService.add(pushMessage) //Add subscription.
           subscribeService.getSubscription(pushMessage.recipient) //return new subscription.
        }
```

Comment: That's correct because the add method is void (unit?) but what approach would be good then? I could use a normal try catch but I feel like that's a lot for something i hoped could be easier

Comment: @user16391449 I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: Alright I'm kinda hesitant with using if statements as i start learning kotlin because it seemed we kinda got rid of that, guess not. That's great thanks

Comment: @user16391449 Sure, if you want to do it without if-else statement, you would have to fix the return types first. Return types are crucial to the Functional Programming nature of kotlin. Please accept my answer if it was helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following construction

```kotlin
val recipientSubscription = subscribeService.getSubscription(pushMessage.recipient)
        ?: run {
               cachingService.add(pushMessage)
               subscribeService.createSubscription() // some theoretical method that creates subscription
        }
```

assuming that `subscribeService.createSubscription()` method's return type is same as `subscribeService.getSubscription()`'s